# Sphinx Search and Laravel

Tags: php, search, laravel, eloquent, sphinx

Installed this package on my laravel project :

http://packalyst.com/packages/package/scalia/sphinxsearch

Everything went fine during installation. I can't get values from database.

this is config.php file of the package :

```
<?php

return array (
    'host'    => '127.0.0.1',
    'port'    => 9312,
    'indexes' => array (
        'user_index' => array ( 'table' => 'user', 'column' => 'user_id', 'modelname' => 'User' ),
    )
);
```

and here's my function, to see the values :

```
$results = SphinxSearch::search('user_index')->get();

var_dump($results);
```

and it returns **bool(false)**

Why i can't get values from my database ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what's 'user_index' for it should your search query.

Comment: Did you check `SphinxSearch::getErrorMessage()` ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sphinx search requires the Sphinx search binary to be installed, unfortunately that link you have provided doesn't specify if it installs sphinx as well - I would be surprised if it did so you probably need to install it yourself. Sphinx isn't just a simple plugin that searches on your database - it builds indexes based on queries you provide in the configuration file and then searches those indexes rather than directly searching your database.

Sphinx search can be downloaded [here](http://sphinxsearch.com/)

If you are on Ubuntu / Debian it could even just be as simple as:

```
sudo apt-get install sphinxsearch
```

I have an example of a really simple Sphinx Config for the search daemon that you can use as a reference [on my Github here](https://github.com/voycey/Sphinx-CakePHP/blob/master/sphinx.conf)

Comment: installation of sphinx is not that easy on Centos 7, had to find the rpm files for installation, configured it, created indexes and sources, but still i get the same error message.

Comment: Have you updated /etc/sphinxsearch/sphinx.conf (or whatever location you installed it to) with your correct MySQL database credentials? Sphinx will need to connect to it separately and you also have to tell Sphinx to use MySQL (As per my configuration file)

Comment: Yes i did that too, wrote my own credentials.

Comment: ensure that you haven't set `listen  = 9307` in that config, that plugin you have installed uses port 9312 as default so at least set it to `listen = 9312`

Comment: Okay i will try this one.

Comment: Voycey i haven't been able to try it yet but be sure i will let you know. I changed entire project so i have to configure from the beginning.